# husky_navigation gmapping_demo.launch not updating

Tags: ros, rviz, clearpath, husky, gmapping-demo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello again,

I am using the husky_navigation gmapping_demo.launch to try mapping my lab. Everything is set up properly (as far as I know anyway) but when I launch the program rviz only shows the first scan. I used rviz to show the laser scan and that is sending data. It seems for some reason that the map won't update after the initial scan. Anyone know the reason for this?

UPDATE
So, I think I have figured out what I did wrong, but I am having trouble fixing it. I used a static transform to connect the odom tf to the base_footprint tf. It appears though that the map will only update when it detects a change between those tfs, but since I used a static transform it will never change and therefore the map will never update. How can I attach the /map->/odom tf tree to the /base_footprint tf tree without using a static transform?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58741/husky_navigation-gmapping_demo.launch-not-updating/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-03-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-03-25**:
Regarding your update: Thats exactly what I mentioned. Maybe you should mark this as completed, as we found the reason for gmapping not working and ask a new question about getting reasonable odometry data from a husky robot.

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-03-25**:
Just closing with stating "...right answer was accepted" doesn't accept the answer by itself. :)

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-03-25**:
That was the closest option from the list. There was no "This question has turned into another question" option :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Judging from [this](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/clearpath_husky/blob/master/husky_navigation/config/gmapping_husky.launch) the `map_update_interval` is set quite high. This may lead to slower map updates.

Does your odometry give you reasonable movement data? In general GMapping updates the map after some minimal translational or angular movement of the robot. This is controlled by the `linearUpdate` and `angularUpdate` paramters. (See: [GMapping parameters](http://ros.org/wiki/gmapping#Parameters)) If no movement is detected (by the odom -> base_link transform), no new scans are integrated into the map.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2013-03-20**:
The laser scan outline moves fairly well as I move the robot, but I have not checked the parameters directly. I shall give that a shot tomorrow.